# What is the expected value of this process?

Tags: probability, expected-value, combinatorics

There are $n$ piles each containing  $a_i$ stones.  In a sequence of moves, Alex chooses two neighbouring piles randomly (containing, say, $A$ and $B$ stones) and combines them to create a single pile with $A + B$ stones at the same place. Such a move also yields him  $A + B$ points. He does this repeatedly until there is one pile.
Alex's score is the sum of all points after all $ n-1$ moves. *What is the expected value of Alex's score?*

I am stuck at this.  I found there are $(n-1)!$ possible move sequences, but I couldn't find how many points we get in all possible ways.

Comment: "Linear pile" is confusing.  Do you mean there are $n$ piles *arranged in a row* and indexed $1,2,\ldots, n$ in order, with $a_i$ stones in pile $i$?

Comment: Yes ,exactly !!

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult -- parts of the solution are related to obscure combinatorial properties of the Symmetric groups -- and I don't think there's a simple closed-form solution.  But we can still make substantial progress.

#### Step 1: Simplification

The key is that the total point value is a *linear* function of the $a_i.$

That is, let there be a sequence of pile "values" (which can be any numbers whatsoever, not just counts) $A = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n).$  The choices in the procedure are a sequence  of random integers $\Sigma = (\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \ldots, \sigma_{n-1})$ where  for each index $i$ $\sigma_i$ is chosen uniformly and independently from the numbers $1,2,\ldots, n-i$ to indicate that the values at positions $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_i + 1$ will be combined (and earned).  Let

$$f(A;\Sigma)$$

be the total points earned.  Given any two sequences $A$ and $B$ of length $n,$ it is straightforward to check that

$$f(A+B;\Sigma) = f(A;\Sigma) + f(B;\Sigma).$$

The problem asks for a formula for the expectation $E[f(A;\Sigma)]$ in terms of $A.$  By linearity of expectation, it will suffice to find a formula for any set of vectors that generate all such $A.$  A convenient set is the basis $(e_j)_{j=1,2,\ldots, n}$ where

$$e_j = (0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,0,\ldots,0)$$

has a $1$ in location $j$ and zeros everwhere else.  Clearly

$$A = a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2 + \cdots + a_n e_n$$

and therefore

$$E[f(A;\Sigma)] = a_1 E[f(e_1;\Sigma)] + a_2 E[f(e_2;\Sigma)] + \cdots + a_n E[f(e_n;\Sigma)].\tag{*}$$

#### Step 2: Recursive solution

In this solution we will play the game one step at a time and need to keep track of $n.$  To this end, let $e_{j;n}$ be the basis element with $n$ components and a $1$ in position $j,$ where $1 \le j \le n.$  Similarly let $\Sigma_n$ refer to the random variable corresponding to $n-1$ steps in the game.

There are two cases to consider.

1. Starting with $e_{1;n},$ there is a $1/(n-1)$ chance that the first two places will be chosen and combined.  This yields $1+0=1$ point for Alex and changes the piles to the configuration $e_{1;n-1}.$  Therefore $$E[f(e_{1;n};\Sigma_n)] = \frac{1}{n-1} + E[f(e_{1;n-1};\Sigma_{n-1})].$$  By symmetry (reversing the sequence of pile values) a similar relation holds for $e_{n;n}.$
2. Otherwise, starting with $A= e_{j;n}$ where $1\lt j \lt n,$

   - There is a $2/(n-1)$ chance position $j$ will be combined with one of its neighbors $j\pm 1$ to give Alex one point.
   - There is a $(j-1)/(n-1)$ chance any combination will involve positions preceding $j$ and a $(n-j)/(n-1)$ chance positions following $j$ will be combined.  This gives two possible new configurations $e_{j-1;n-1}$ and $e_{j;n-1}.$

> Thus, $$E[f(e_{j;n};\Sigma_n)] = \frac{1}{n-1}\left(2 + (j-1)E[f(e_{j-1;n-1};\Sigma_{n-1})] + (n-j+1)E[f(e_{j;n-1};\Sigma_{n-1})]\right).$$

This yields an infinite triangular matrix of expectations.  The rows are indexed by $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ and the columns by $j.$  Here is the array $((n-1)!E[f(e_{j;n};\Sigma(n)])$ for $n=1, 2, \ldots, 8,$ where the expectations are multiplied by $(n-1)!$ to give integer values:

$$\begin{array}{r|llllllllll}
\text{n} & & & & & & & & & &\\
1&0& & & & & & & & & \\
2&1&1& & & & & & & & \\
3&3&4&3& & & & & & & \\
4&11&15&15&11& & & & & & \\
5&50&68&72&68&50& & & & & \\
6&274&370&400&400&370&274& & & & \\
7&1764&2364&2580&2640&2580&2364&1764& & & \\
8&13068&17388&19068&19740&19740&19068&17388&13068& & \\
\vdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\ddots&
\end{array}$$

**The rows of this matrix (each divided by $(n-1)!$) give the coefficients of the $a_j$ to use in the formula $(*).$**

#### Step 3: Verification

Here are the results of playing this game with $n=20$ piles for each of the starting positions $j=1,2,\ldots, 20,$ 5000 times each.  The dotted line plots the recursive solution for reference.  The deviations between the simulated results and the recursive solution can be attributed to random variation.

[image: Figure]

Having some confidence the recursive solution is correct, we may study it for larger $n,$ as in this plot for $n=10,000:$

[image: Figure 2]

The values at the endpoints $j=1,n$ grow exponentially (in $n$) close to $\log(n) + \gamma$ (Euler's $\gamma \approx 0.5772157$).  The curve peaks in the middle near $2\log n$ and is (obviously) symmetric under $j \to n+1-j$ (corresponding to reversing the order of the piles).

The code to compute these solutions using the recursion is efficient, requiring $O(N^2)$ calculations to obtain all solutions for $n=1,2,\ldots, N.$  This version takes one second for $n=10,000$ (but to save space, outputs only the solution for $N$ itself in the array `X`).

```R
N <- 1e4
X <- c(0, rep(NA, N-1))
for (n in 2:N) {
  j <- seq_len(n-1)[-1]
  X[c(1,j,n)] <- c(1+(n-1)*X[1], 2+(j-1)*X[j-1] + (n-j)*X[j], 1+(n-1)*X[n-1]) / (n-1)
}
```

Incidentally, the first *column* of the solutions, $1,3,11,50,274,\ldots,$ [counts many things,](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C11%2C50%2C274%2C1764%2C13068&language=english&go=Search) such as the total number of cycles in all permutations of $n$ things.  The second column is also a known sequence, but subsequent columns do not appear to have been noticed.

Answer (score 1):

For a closed-form solution, notice that the number of times $a_i$ is summed in all $\Gamma(n)$ possible move sequences is

$(H_{i-1}+H_{n-i})\Gamma(n)$

where $H_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ harmonic number, with $H_0\equiv0$.

So Alex's expected score is

$\sum_i{a_i(H_{i-1}+H_{n-i})}$

This result matches the matrix provided by @whuber (with R):

```
f <- function(n) {
  h <- c(0, cumsum(1/seq_len(n - 1L)))
  (h + rev(h))*gamma(n)
}
m <- matrix(0, 8, 8)
m[upper.tri(m, TRUE)] <- unlist(lapply(1:8, f))
t(m)
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]
#> [1,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> [2,]     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> [3,]     3     4     3     0     0     0     0     0
#> [4,]    11    15    15    11     0     0     0     0
#> [5,]    50    68    72    68    50     0     0     0
#> [6,]   274   370   400   400   370   274     0     0
#> [7,]  1764  2364  2580  2640  2580  2364  1764     0
#> [8,] 13068 17388 19068 19740 19740 19068 17388 13068
```

Comment: Thank you for the beautiful simplification!